# Why put a period after your name in the closing of a communication/E-mail?

Tags: punctuation, formality, email, periods, valediction

I have several co-workers in Europe and all of them tend to put a period after their names in the closing of E-mails, e.g.:

> Thanks,
>   Matt.

I've never seen this, so I am curious if it is proper form to put a period after your name in a communication.

Comment: I'm in the U.S. and have never seen this.

Comment: I'm in the UK and I've not seen this either.

Comment: I'm neither from the US nor from the UK, but i haven't seen this either.

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit more ~ which countries are they from?  Is it really "all" of them?  Or just "many" of them?  Do they all work for the same company?

Comment: J.R.: Brazil, France, Scotland (UK), Lebanon; enjoy.

Comment: Especially since (IIRC) the early Unix email client used a single dot on a line to end the message.

Comment: @mbrown: I didn't ask for me, I asked on behalf of the community. When the first three people who answer all say they've never seen it before, that begs for more information - for some extra clue to help unlock the mystery. (I had wondered if maybe they all worked for one company, where the company president did this for some odd reason, and several others simply followed suit. But mgb may be onto something...)

Comment: Actually, I did send mgb an upvote because that _may_ be a reason, but not here.  These guys live in the Windows world (but are devs).  Any way, I suspect it is a mix of over-compensating for the risk of incorrect grammar (due to English being most of these guys second written language), and the other guy following suit.  Or maybe it's just what John said below.  /mb.

Comment: @mgb A single dot on a line *by itself*. Ending a signature line with a dot has nothing to do with e-mail.

Comment: @MετάEd - no but it was very easy in the days of text terminals to do <CR> then "." which ended and sent the message - so if you weren't a touch typist you tended to avoid "."

Comment: @mgb The community which faced that scenario was very small. This does not explain why most people do not put a period after their name.

Comment: @MετάEd, most peopel do not put a period after their name because, unless they were trained as secretaries in the 1950s, they don't know you should. Additionally people skip punctuation in informal messages such as email and sms

Comment: @mgb You say "you should", but it does not make sense to prescribe a practice because it was common sixty years ago (if, indeed, it was).

Comment: Yes. This is proper letter writing etiquette.

Comment: I've been told that, long before email existed, (1) my grandfather used to put a period after his signature on handwritten letters, (2) this was unusual enough that he was sometimes asked to explain why he did it, and (3) his explanation was "so that people don't continue reading".

Comment: A period after the signature is weird and pretentious. Just depends for what you're going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email is not subject to normal punctuation conventions.

It's probably just a personal idiosyncracy, like putting a hyphen before a signature initial.

-j

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Ireland and I see this quite a bit, in letters and email and from different companies & countries — it doesn't matter. The only pattern that I can make out is that it seems to appear a lot with the shortened form of someone's name, e.g. *Matt.* instead of *Matthew*, *Ed.* instead of *Edward*. I have also noticed it when people use just their first name and not surname e.g. *John*. I'm still searching for a definitive answer, though.